# svn log stops at start of branch

Tags: svn, pysvn

I am running the command `svn log D:\mybranch` which was checked out from a Subversion branch. Mybranch in turn was made using `svn copy` off the trunk. The problem is, the `svn log` command is only showing revisions made on the actual branch. But I want it to include changes on the trunk as well.

For example:

- revisions 1 to 100 were made on the trunk
- I created the branch at revision 101 using svn copy
- revisions 102-110 were made on the branch
- I then checked out the branch to `D:\mybranch`
- I ran svn log `D:\mybranch`, but it only shows revisions 101-110.

  Using TortoiseSVN, however, if I right click on `D:\mybranch` and click "TortoiseSVN->Show log" then it shows me revisions 1-110. (I have "Stop on copy/rename" un-checked on Tortoise SVN).

My question is, how can I get `svn log` to show the same behavior as "TortoiseSVN->Show log" and include the history from the trunk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not about Subversion command-line client; `svn log` displays full history unless you specify [`--stop-on-copy` option](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.stop_on_copy).

On the other hand, Pysvn operates differently. [It has this option enabled, by default](http://tools.ietf.org/doc/python-svn/pysvn_prog_ref.html#pysvn_client_log). That's why you see only partial log. Setting `strict_node_history=False` should help.

Comment: Thanks, that's great. Cant believe I missed that when I checked the documentation..